# reducing time complexity for biginteger problem in java

Tags: java, sorting, biginteger

In this problem we have to sort the element but the element are in biginteger format so for that i have done some effort but some testcases are not getting passed due to timeout so please suggest me how to decrease the time complexity.

```
static String[] bigSorting(String[] unsorted) {

    BigInteger big[]=new BigInteger[unsorted.length];
    String str[]=new String[unsorted.length];
    for(int i=0;i<unsorted.length;i++)
    {
        big[i]=new BigInteger(unsorted[i]);

    }
    Arrays.sort(big);
    for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        str[i]=sb.append(big[i]).toString();

    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Can you isolate which part takes the most time? Conversion to BigInteger and back to String, or the actual sorting? If you don't have to do any actual calculations, you could zero-pad all the strings to have the same length and then just sort the strings, maybe that's faster.

Comment: Also, why `new StringBuffer("").append(big[i]).toString()` instead of just `big[i].toString()`?

Comment: Why are you creating a `StringBuffer`?

Comment: Ha snap @tobias_k

Comment: from my point of view possibilities goes to Arrays.sort()

Comment: @tobias_k i tried big[i].toString() but it showing same testcases failed

Comment: I did not expect the StringBuffer part to be the problem, but it's kind of messy and unneccesary.

Comment: This can be done in one line with streams...

Comment: @BenR. because of its low time complexity for appending.initially i used ""+big[i].

Comment: @tobias_k ya i tried several method for conversion into string format but still same result is coming

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with String formatting or time complexity. Post the stack traces of the failing test cases?

Answer (score 2):

I would not turn the strings into BigIntegers at all. You do this so you can sort the strings on their integer values. The following assumes all strings contain positive or 0 BigInteger values, i.e. no negatives. Otherwise the code gets a little more complicated (WRT the lengths).

I would simply sort the string array directly, using a custom Comparator:

```
public class BIComp implements Comparator<String>
{
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        if (s1.length() > s2.length())
            return 1;
        else if (s1.length() < s2.length())
            return -1;
        else
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}


...
Arrays.sort(str, new BIComp());
```

Comment: this is fine but editor don't allow me to edit the code. i have to write merely the function which i have provided.

Comment: anyhow thanks for the suggestion it is very helpful.

Comment: @RAVI: I assume you can write your own simple quicksort. Then you can use any sorting criterion you like. Should be pretty easy that way.